# Exception class constructor

Tags: apex, exception

I would like to know what are the constructors of `Exception` class in Salesforce.

I am aware of these two constructors, is there any other?

```
Exception()
Exception(String message)
```

We know that Salesforce is made over Java, so can we expect Salesforce to have the same set of "Constructors" as of java

[Link here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)

Also, I would like to know if there is a way to know how the `Exception` class is written in Salesforce.

Comment: That last question is probably not on topic here. Even if it is on topic, try to stick to one question per question.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson,
Thanks for your response. Kindly let me know whether I should raise a new question for the last topic..
Otherwise, if you know the answer, please let me know.

Comment: As I said, the last question is almost certainly off topic on this forum, even if you create a separate question for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are also `Exception` constructors that accept another `Exception`. Take a look at [Creating Custom Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_custom.htm), which shows constructors you can define on a class that simply extends `Exception` without any custom body.

> To create your custom exception class, extend the built-in Exception class and make sure your class name ends with the word Exception. Append extends Exception after your class declaration as follows.
>
> ```
> public class MyException extends Exception {}
> ```
>
> Here are some ways you can create your exceptions objects, which you can then throw.
>
> You can construct exceptions:
>
> - With no arguments:
>
>   ```
>     new MyException();
>   ```
> - With a single String argument that specifies the error message:
>
>   ```
>     new MyException('This is bad');
>   ```
> - With a single Exception argument that specifies the cause and that displays in any stack trace:
>
>   ```
>     new MyException(e);
>   ```
> - With both a String error message and a chained exception cause that displays in any stack trace:
>
>   ```
>     new MyException('This is bad', e);
>   ```

So there are at least two that you did not list (the last two). The document I linked does not claim to be comprehensive, but I believe these are indeed all of the public constructors.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the link. Everything is described here as per **MyException** class. But I'm more interested on **Exception** class.

`public class MyException extends Exception {}`

Comment: @Robi That's where the constructors come from...